# Fast, easy and simple construction of a log store

Tags: wood, construction

We've just bought a whopping great log burner, and so our thoughts have turned to keeping it fed over the winter. I've plenty of ash trees, some beech, and an old sycamore that over the last couple of years have provided logs, but they're scattered around the garden slowly rotting.

Before they become completely unusable I'd like to dry them (and the good logs) out under cover. I've space down at the bottom of our property that's sheltered under trees so I'm going to build a wood store there and over-winter logs for next autumn.

I don't want to make a drama of this and make something elegant and beautiful, not least as the space I've in mind is tucked away in a copse and therefore invisible! So I was just going to get some treated 3x3 fence posts, some pre-built fence panels, and roof over with ply and roofing felt. I'll most likely create a raised "floor" of longish bits of old timber propped up on old bricks. The front will be left open and I'll most likely leave the rear apex of the roof open too so everything can breathe but is dry.

Would this work? Any suggestions, in particular for making sure the edifice is properly fixed to the ground?

Comment: Its been 10 years, is your wood shed keeping your wood dry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily use something like [this.](http://www.homedepot.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?storeId=10051&productId=100655352&langId=-1&catalogId=10053&MERCH=REC-_-nosearch-1-_-NA-_-100655352-_-N&locStoreNum=1402&marketID=113)

[image: metal fence post spike]

It's often called a metpost or metal fence spike, depending on your region.

Comment: Ah yes, what I over here know as a "metpost". Had that in mind, I hope I don't come across any big roots!

Comment: And that is indeed what I used to rather good effect. Rather than use pallets, I used six-foot fence panels, and a rough-and-ready pitched roof made of OSB3 board with roofing felt over. The floor is made of treated boards a foot or so off the ground with an inch gap between them for air. So far, so good -- it's down in the trees so it seems unlikely to blow away unless I'm really unlucky.

Comment: This is why "link only" answers are _strongly_ discouraged. Not shocklingly, that link is now dead and this answer is now useless without any description of what "this" is, so nobody can attempt to find it elsewhere.

Comment: Doh! Yeah, that's something I would never do /now/. Fortunately there was enough context to find the thing.

Answer (score 4):

In the past, I've used lattice layed over a 2x4 frame as a floor.  This works well to get some ventilation from the bottom.  I've also used lattice on the sides as well.  Don't worry too much about keeping the logs perfectly dry.  What you want is good airflow so that any surface moisture can dry quickly.  You probably also want to think about having a few sections, so that you can add new wood to one section, and take older seasoned wood from a different section.

I've also heard about people just nailing together four pallets to make a three sided box.  If you have a tractor with pallet forks, this also makes it easy to move wood next to the house as needed.

Comment: I like the idea of sections.